# Is my networking plan reasonable?

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan, home-networking

I would first of all like to start off by saying that I am a software developer by profession, so my networking knowledge is relatively basic.  My question is therefore aimed at figuring out if I am on the right track, or if there are better alternatives to what I want to accomplish.

I am about to set up a home network for a new place that I bought.  I have been giving it a lot of thought and would like to be connected in a wired manner as much as possible (I want wifi throughout the house, but only for mobile deviced - my PCs must be wired).

I have identified that I have 3 rooms in total which require ethernet jacks in them.  The first room is a study which will have 2 PCs and a network printer.  So as a minimum, I require 3 points in that room to be able to connect an ethernet cable directly into PC 1, PC2 and the printer.

I then want 2 other points in the spare bedroom, and one more in the main bedroom (incase I would like to put a wireless router in that room just incase the wifi from the source will not reach there). So the point in the main bedroom will be plugged into a wireless router for wireless devices to connect.

So my reasoning is the following (please correct me if I am wrong):

The source of the internet from my ISP is in my living room, where this will go into the WAN port of my router.  From the router I will then connect a network switch into one of the available LAN ports (with around 8 ports or so).  The other ports in the router will be kept free for any network TV devices I may need in the living room.

The network switch will then have an ethernet cable plugged into each ports, where each cable runs to the points in the other rooms.  I am assuming that each point in a room will be connected directly to the switch with one long cat5e cable.  So when I plug the ethernet cable in the study into PC 1, that will be a very long cable running all the way to the switch.  Same applies to PC 2 and the printer - these are two separate very long cables.

So in total, I would be having around 6 very long ethernet cables running from the switch into the other rooms, where one cable is used for just one device.

Is this all valid reasoning? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? My electrician who is wiring the place suggested that I use one ethernet cable and loop it for all devices, but he said he does not know anything about networking so has instructed me to seek professional advice.  What I am writing here is basically what I have come up with.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Are you planning on running the cables through the walls?

Comment: Yes correct - will be putting conduits for them

Comment: Yes, you got the basics right. All cables go from the switch to their destination PC, not one cable that goes from pc to pc. This is old technology (token ring or coax)

Comment: "Looping" one cable might work for telephone – or with coaxial 10BASE-2 in the 1980's, which was a shared medium – but don't even try that with modern Ethernet.

Comment: Basically correct. You might want to consider if you really need several ethernet sockets in each room. Depends on the room size/convenience really - because you could have just one cable for each room and then put in a switch in the room to add *n* new ethernet ports there - which takes less ports on your main switch (one per room). I also found that for home setup - if I do not want to have these long ethernet cables and I do not require 1GB speed - I can do with powerline adapters to connect a room switch to my main switch.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, your plan is correct. An alternative that I have seen is to run *one* line to each room from the main switch (where your internet service enters the house/apartment), and set up an additional switch in each room that will have multiple wired devices in it; this would minimize the number of extremely long cables that need be used (and the amount of conduit that you have to run in the walls). The disadvantage of this alternative is that you have unsightly cables "loose" in the room.

There are other refinements possible regarding wiring, but none of them really changes the basics that you've already correctly worked out for yourself.

Comment: It might not matter much, but depending on the usage the difference between "1 Gbps per device" and "1 Gbps per room" might end up noticeable...

Comment: @grawity - I can't see it making any real difference in a home network, unless the OP is planning on running his own server for a MMORPG or something like that - his incoming internet is unlikely to be that fast, and most devices probably can't really process the data fast enough to make a difference.